# Error in hyperledger fabric writing your first app using windows 10

Tags: windows, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am following the getting started guide in the URL below

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I installed all prerequisites.

Using windows 10.

After installation of prerequisites   I move to next section “Write your First Application” URL given below

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html

After download “fabric-sample” from git  when I try “startFabric.sh” script in “fabcar” subdirectory for launch the network I am  encountering an error are show below.

UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing /etc/hyperledger/fabric/C:/Program Files/Git/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp folder

Comment: Hi ! may I know where/tool are you issuing this command on windows? cygwin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the path of the missing file you'll see it is malformed.  It was resolved by issuing an export command before running the startFabric.sh script:

export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

./startFabric.sh

See https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5392?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel.

Thanks Tim & Gari